# Customize dropdown using jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-mobile

We are developing our application using jquery mobile and mvc4. jquery mobile is best for mobile but customization does look easy.

As per client requirement the drop down should look like below.

[image]

But My drop down is look like below one.

[image]

Below is my DOM structure

[image]

Below is my MVC dropdown.

```
@Html.DropDownList("selectW",
       new SelectList(ViewBag.User, "Value","Text",@ViewBag.Selected))
```

I need to remove .ui-btn style and it should satisfy my client requirement.Please guide me

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('#selectWhse-button').removeClass('.ui-btn');
```

That will remove the class from your div

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all. I made data-role=none. so jquery mobile didnt customize my dropdown. I used below css to apply my own css.

```
new {@data_role="none" , @style="background-color:#3B3131;color:#72B6F2;font-size:20px", @class="styleselect" }
```